# How to do an EVAL expression in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a column that has numbers separated by commas. I want to add all the numbers together for each record. Using the *spexecuteSQL* I have got this far, but it's still not evaluating the field. How do I do it?

**eg.** field is '4,5,5' transpose to 4+5+5 but want to evaluate and get ---> 14

```
declare @com as nvarchar(100)
set @com= 'select replace(class_historyTY,'','',''+'') from #aety1'

exec sp_executesql @com
```

Comment: Creating a "math string" of "4+5+5" won't work. You'll have to search around for a split function to take your '4,5,5' and make it 3 rows, and then use sum() on that column

Comment: you only wants to `ADD` right ? or you have more complex asthmatics to perform ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SQL Server 2016, following should work:

```
select name, sum(cast(t.value as int)) from
(select name, cs.Value
from details
cross apply STRING_SPLIT (name, ',') cs) t
group by name
```

where my table looks like:

```
details
---------------
name
--------------
1,2,3,4
---------------
10,20,30
```

Result:

```
 name | 
 1,2,3,4 | 10
 10,20,30 | 60
```

Answer (score 0):

As the cross apply suggested by Josef is the correct way of doing this you wated a solution with `sp_executesql`:

```
Declare @s nvarchar(max) = 'select ' 
                + (select replace(class_historyTY,',','+')  from #aety1) 
exec sp_executesql  @s
```

the idea here is to make your sum string first `4+5+5` and than wrap it in select statement and that expression `select 4+5+5` is passed to `sp_executesql`.

Answer (score 0):

ORACLE solution:

```
xmlquery( expr returning content ).getNumberVal()
```

The point is to replace '/' by ' div ', +,-,* operators remain the same.

Example:

```
-- operations, possible numbers and result defined, find number positions
with src(op,p) as (
   select ' + ', 1 from dual union all
   select ' - ', 2 from dual union all
   select ' * ', 4 from dual union all
   select ' div ',8 from dual 
) ,
vals(val,p) AS (
   select 1, 1 from dual union all
   select 3, 2 from dual union all
   select 4, 4 from dual union all
   select 5, 8 from dual union all
   select 7, 16 from dual 
)
select expr, value from (
   select replace(expr, 'div','÷') as expr, xmlquery(expr returning content).getNumberVal() as value from (
       select '(((' || d1.val || s1.op || d2.val || ')' || s2.op || d3.val || ')' || s3.op || d4.val || ')' || s4.op || d5.val as expr
           from 
               src s1, src s2, src s3, src s4,
               vals d1, vals d2, vals d3, vals d4, vals d5
           where 
               s1.p + s2.p + s3.p + s4.p = 15 
               AND
               d1.p + d2.p + d3.p + d4.p + d5.p = 31 
               AND (
                   (s1.op = ' + '
                   AND s2.op = ' div '
                   AND s3.op = ' * '
                   AND s4.op = ' - '
                   )
               )
   )
)
WHERE 
    value = 1
;
/*
(((7 + 1) ÷ 4) * 3) - 5  1
(((5 + 1) ÷ 3) * 4) - 7  1
(((1 + 7) ÷ 4) * 3) - 5  1
(((1 + 5) ÷ 3) * 4) - 7  1
*/
```

Or faster:

```
with vals(val,p) AS (
   select 1, 1 from dual union all
   select 3, 2 from dual union all
   select 4, 4 from dual union all
   select 5, 8 from dual union all
   select 7, 16 from dual 
)
select expr || ' = ' || value AS result from (
   select expr, xmlquery(
        '((($v/val/@v1 + $v/val/@v2) div $v/val/@v3) * $v/val/@v4) - $v/val/@v5' 
        passing  
        xmlelement(
            "val",
            xmlattributes(v1 as "v1",
                v2 as "v2",
                v3 as "v3",
                v4 as "v4",
                v5 as "v5")
        ) as "v" 
        returning content).getNumberVal() as value 
    from (
        select 
            '(((' || d1.val || ' + ' || d2.val || ') ÷ ' || d3.val || ') * ' || d4.val || ') - ' || d5.val as expr,
            d1.val as v1, d2.val as v2, d3.val as v3, d4.val as v4, d5.val as v5
        from vals d1, vals d2, vals d3, vals d4, vals d5
        where d1.p + d2.p + d3.p + d4.p + d5.p = 31 
    )
   )
WHERE 
    value = 1
;
/*
(((1 + 5) ÷ 3) * 4) - 7 = 1
(((1 + 7) ÷ 4) * 3) - 5 = 1
(((5 + 1) ÷ 3) * 4) - 7 = 1
(((7 + 1) ÷ 4) * 3) - 5 = 1
*/
```